# Finding det(A) with standard basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

For example, let $e_1  = [1 \quad 0]$ and $e_2 = [0 \quad 1] $be standard basis vectors. A is a $2 \times 2$ matrix. $Ae_1 = [-3\quad 7]$ and $Ae2 = [3 \quad 5] $ 
How do I find the $\det(A)$?

Comment: Obtain $A$ and apply the formula for $2\times 2$ determinants.

Comment: @Bernard. That is where I'm stuck. How do I obtain A?

Comment: Its columns are the coordinates of the images of the basis vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$, then
\begin{align}
&A = \begin{bmatrix}
a&b \\ c&d
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
-3 \\ 7
\end{bmatrix} \implies a = -3, \quad \text{and} \quad c = 7 \\
&A = \begin{bmatrix}
a&b \\ c&d
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
3 \\ 5
\end{bmatrix} \implies b = 3, \quad \text{and} \quad d = 5.\\
& \qquad\text{therefore, }\det \begin{vmatrix}
A 
\end{vmatrix} = \det\begin{vmatrix}
-3 & 3 \\ 7 & 5
\end{vmatrix}  = -15-21 = -36.
\end{align}

Comment: Ahh I see. Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar question. Say we have two vectors u = [1 -1] and v = [1 1]  (which aren't the basis)and Au and Av are given. To find det(A) would I follow the same procedure?

Comment: @Uberi_Puip Yes it's exactly the same procedure but with one small extra step where instead of having directly the values of the constants , i.e., $a=-3$ or $c=7$, you'll have a linear system of equations, in which you'll have to express $a$ in terms of $b$ and vice-versa

Comment: @hitechphysics No need to go through all of that. Since $A=[Au\;Av]\,[u\;v]^{-1}$, $\det(A)=\det([Au\;Av])/\det([u\;v])$.

Comment: @amd I know but given the nature and mathematical sophistication of the OP's question I felt it was necessary to go through steps which you might consider trivial. The method you're providing will most likely not be of help 
 to someone at his/her level.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ is 2 by 2 matrix, its first column is $Ae_1=[-3, 7]$ and second column is $Ae_2=[3,5]$
$Det(A) =\left|\matrix{-3 & 3\\5& 7}\right|$

Answer (score 0):

Since A is a 2x2 matrix, simply use the formula for finding determinants for 2x2 matrices.

\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}

The formula is ad-bc. In this case, A$e_1$ = \begin{bmatrix}-3\\7\end{bmatrix}
And A$e_2$ = \begin{bmatrix}3\\5\end{bmatrix}
Combine these vectors to get: \begin{bmatrix}-3&3\\7&5\end{bmatrix}
Using the formula, det(A) = (-3 $\cdot$ 5) - (3 $\cdot$ 7) = (-15) - (21) = -36.

Comment: Thank you. Would the columns still be the same if e1 and e2 were not basis vectors?